# Setting root folder for FolderBrowser

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

How do i Set the root folder for a folderdialog?

My sample does not seem to work. (I checked that the folder exists)

```
    Dim FolderBrowserDialog1 As New FolderBrowserDialog

    FolderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = "C:\VaultWorkspace\cadcampc\"

    If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        Copy_Design_New_Loc.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End If
```

Error message

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "C:\VaultWorkspace\cadcampc\" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

What do I need to do to set my custom location as rootfolder?

Comment: But with a so clear error message why not trying to understand it, rather than posting a question here? It says that an Integer is expected. Why not checking what RootFolder is (just putting the mouse on the variable would be enough to know that it is a System.Environment.SpecialFolder); after a quick search you would get: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.100).aspx It is an Enum (= can be accessed via indices or by typing the whole values, where VS can be very helpful). That is: you cannot input anything, but have to choose among a list of folders.

Comment: But, there must be a way to use another folder than the predefined special folders?

Comment: Your question was "What do I do wrong?" and my answer was that you should have known it after a quick analysis. The question "is there any other alternative?" is different. In any case, I can also answer this one: by default (= using FolderBrowserDialog as it is) there is none. On the other hand, it does not seem to be a big deal (there quite a few special folders and the initial folder is not a so important feature). If you think otherwise, you should create your own approach.

Comment: Use SelectedPath instead of RootFolder when starting in a standard folder. This issue has been a weak point forever with this dialog. The next issue you'll see even when you do get it to start in a folder the selected item is often off screen and the user has to scroll down and know what to look for. Search `use openfiledialog for folder selection` for alternatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FolderBrowserDialog has always been a margin tool IMO.

When opening a standard mapped folder you can use `RootFolder` to remove some clutter. `SelectedPath` will open the parent folder and  highlight your folder but it may be off screen. Your posted path may look OK as it most likely has a small number of folders to display and the selected one should be visible.

```
    FolderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
    FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = "C:\temp"
    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        MsgBox(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
    End If
```

Tested on Win7 .Net 4 VS2013 VB.Net WinForms

---

Here's a variation that doesn't need the control on the form:

```
    Using fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
        fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
        fbd.SelectedPath = "H:\temp\scans"
        If fbd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            MsgBox(fbd.SelectedPath)
        End If
    End Using
```

---

Here's a way to use the `OpenFileDialog`, far from perfect but better than folder dialog IMO, and simpler than a subclass:

```
    Using obj As New OpenFileDialog
        obj.Filter = "foldersOnly|*.none"
        obj.CheckFileExists = False
        obj.CheckPathExists = False
        obj.InitialDirectory = "C:\temp"
        obj.CustomPlaces.Add("H:\OIS") ' add your custom location, appears upper left
        obj.CustomPlaces.Add("H:\Permits") ' add your custom location
        obj.Title = "Select folder - click Open to return opened folder name"
        obj.FileName = "OpenFldrPath"
        If obj.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            MsgBox(IO.Directory.GetParent(obj.FileName).FullName)
        End If
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using FolderBrowserDialogEx: A C# customization of FolderBrowserDialog.

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=159352

It might be a pain to run it through an online code translator though ( to change it to VB .NET ).  This folder browser is MUCH better than the regular one.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question - not a regular here ... but thought I could post something useful, which people looking for a similar answer might appreciate ...

I use the following function to return the value of a selected folder ...

```
Imports System.Diagnostics.Process
Imports System.Windows.Forms

...

    Public Function SetWorkingPath() As String
        Try
            Dim folderDlg As New System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog

            With folderDlg
                .ShowNewFolderButton = True
                .Description = "Selected your working folder. This is where your PDF files will be saved."
                .RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
                .SelectedPath = IIf(Len(Trim(WorkingPath)) = 0, Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer, WorkingPath)
                If (.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
                    SetWorkingPath = .SelectedPath
                Else
                    SetWorkingPath = ""
                End If
            End With
        Catch e As Exception
            MsgBox(e.Message + " (" + e.ToString() + ")", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SetWorkingPath Error")
            SetWorkingPath = ""
        End Try

        WorkingPath = SetWorkingPath
    End Function
```

Hope this helps someone ...

DWE

Answer (score 0):

JefE, you asked if there is a way to use another root folder than the predefined special folders? have you tried with `Shell.BrowseForFolder` Method?

Try this:

```
    Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0
    Const NO_OPTIONS = &H10&
    Const RootFolder = "C:\VaultWorkspace\"


    Dim objShell As Object = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Dim objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(WINDOW_HANDLE, "Select Folder:", NO_OPTIONS, RootFolder)

    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Copy_Design_New_Loc.Text = objFolder.self.path
    Else
        'Exit on Cancel
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution but I don't know if it exists on earlier VS as I have Visual studio 2022 but here it is anyway for future programmers:

```
Dim folderbrowser1 As New FolderBrowserDialog
folderbrowser1.InitialDirectory = path
folderbrowser1.ShowDialog()
```